# How to compare two Mongodb primitive type Decimal128 in go

Tags: mongodb, go

```
valueA, _ := primitive.ParseDecimal128("123.00")
valueB, _ := primitive.ParseDecimal128("123.12")
```

how to calculate valueA < valueB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer thanks to @Matteo

There is a function converting Decimal128 to BigInt.

and BigInt available to compare

```
func CompareDecimal128(d1, d2 primitive.Decimal128) (int, error) {
    b1, exp1, err := d1.BigInt()
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    b2, exp2, err := d2.BigInt()
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }

    sign := b1.Sign()
    if sign != b2.Sign() {
        if b1.Sign() > 0 {
            return 1, nil
        } else {
            return -1, nil
        }
    }

    if exp1 == exp2 {
        return b1.Cmp(b2), nil
    }

    if sign < 0 {
        if exp1 < exp2 {
            return 1, nil
        }
        return -1, nil
    } else {
        if exp1 < exp2 {
            return -1, nil
        }

        return 1, nil
    }
}
```

*edited for exponential part

Answer (score 1):

Looking in the test [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/blob/9a6cd355da87d3488a5187d8e00461eeae1e5773/bson/bsoncodec/bsoncodec_test.go#L80):

```
func compareDecimal128(d1, d2 primitive.Decimal128) bool {
    d1H, d1L := d1.GetBytes()
    d2H, d2L := d2.GetBytes()

    if d1H != d2H {
        return false
    }

    if d1L != d2L {
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: thanks, but it just checking two decimals are different or same. I'm looking for like a operator "<"